# How to efficiently iterate through 1-d array containing 2-d image data in android?

Tags: java, android, performance, image-processing

I have an image as a 1-d byte array that I need to iterate through to perform a filtering operation. This is the way I'm doing it now:

```
final int height = image.height(), width = image.width();

byte[] imageArray = new byte[image.numberOfPixels() * image.numberOfChannels()];
image.getAsByteArray(imageArray);

byte[] resultArray = new byte[image.numberOfPixels() * image.numberOfChannels()];

for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
    int rowIndex = width * i;
    for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
        int columnIndex = rowIndex + j;     // current index
        int upperRow = columnIndex - width; // go back a row 
        int lowerRow = columnIndex + width/ // go forward a row

        int sum = imageArray[upperRow-1]  + imageArray[upperRow]  + imageArray[upperRow+1] +
                  imageArray[columnIndex-1] + imageArray[columnIndex] + imageArray[columnIndex+1] +
                  imageArray[lowerRow-1]  + imageArray[lowerRow]  + imageArray[lowerRow+1];

        int average = sum / 9;
        resultArray[columnIndex] = (byte) average;
    }
}
```

The above code performs a basic averaging function. I use the loop for performing other filtering functions as well. It's not very fast however. What could I do to iterate through the image array faster?

Comment: Shouldnt you write ur average to another array? You are overwriting your original image before u finish overall smoothing - which may provide false results.. Depending on image size you maybe could just parallelize your algorithm? Maybe you could also do something to avoid amount of cache spills you got now - I am no expert but to me it seems that you have cache spill on every iteration.

Comment: @AleksanderFular - You are absolutely right. I was writing this code from memory and didn't really check before posting. I'll change it.

Comment: You should've shown ur real code here - maybe then someone could tell u what you could be doing otherway.. I would suggest looking for papers which talk about similar issues e.g - http://графикон.рф/2007/proceedings/Papers/Paper_70.pdf - first google result "Box Blur" in this paper

Comment: possible duplicate of [efficient 2d mean filter implementation that minimises redundant memory loads?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5923696/efficient-2d-mean-filter-implementation-that-minimises-redundant-memory-loads)